# Open new Window with given html and javascript (script tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application I want to open a new window (required) which loads following html file.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>billboard.js</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/billboard.js/1.3.0/billboard.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/billboard.js/1.3.0/billboard.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {

            // chart-1
            var chart1 = bb.generate({
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                        ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                    ]
                },
                bindto: "#LineChart-1"
            });
            // chart-2
            var chart1 = bb.generate({
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                        ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                    ]
                },
                bindto: "#LineChart-2"
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>billboard.js show hide points with multiple charts</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Graph-1</h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="LineChart-1" class="bb" style="position: relative;">
                    <svg width="720" height="320" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In the openWindow function i tried the following:

```
window = $window.open('', 'Test', 'width=500,height=400');
myWindow.document.write(ABOVE_HTML_FILE) *OR*  myWindow.document.body.InnerHtml = ABOVE_HTML_FILE
```

Getting following error message:

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script

So I tried replacing the script tags via

```
let script = window.document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
script.defer = true;
window.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Now im getting the error:

> $ is not defined -> Jquery is not available...

Any suggestions? I would really appreciate it

Comment: What happens when you remove jQuery all together, and move the java script that is in the head, to just above the body closing tag (remove the window on load handler also)?

Comment: Huge suggestion @SanderSluis Sander Sluis! It works now! Thank you!!! One small question: What if i need jQuery from start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:
Remove jQuery and the remove the onload handler. Move the inline javascript from the head into the body (just before the body closing tag).

If for some reason you really must use jQuery, you can:

- Put the source inline
- Host it on the same domain as were you call window.open

But ask yourself if you really need jQuery. Nowadays it's rarely ever needed. You can check here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/